# In what circumstances quotes are grammatically acceptable around an indirect quotation or a paraphrase?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

This question is to understand an online spat between the 2021 Nobel Peace Prize recipient Dmitry Muratov and an outspoken political activist Leonid Volkov.

In a [tweet](https://twitter.com/leonidvolkov/status/1443509251691925504) Leonid Volkov ridiculed a recent editorial by Dmitry Muratov in Novaya Gazeta. There he referred to the editorial as an article on the subject of "...", putting a paraphrase of the piece in quotes:

> Сложно меня чем-то впечатлить, но пост Муратова на тему "Венедиктов, отстаивая свои идеалы, вбросил 300 тысяч электронных голосов, чтобы не допустить в Госдуму сталинистов, а вы все не цените!" — это прямо круто.

In his [response](https://novayagazeta.ru/articles/2021/10/06/pismo-l-m-volkovu-v-vynuzhdennuiu-emigratsiiu), Dmitry Muratov asked Leonid Volkov to remove the quotes as a paraphrase is not direct speech, so the quotes are misplaced.

So the question is, in what circumstances quotes can be put around a paraphrase? Could Leonid Volkov's punctuation be justified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the question is, in what circumstances quotes can be put around a paraphrase?

In any circumstances the author deems justifying.

Style guides and grammar books that describe (and prescribe) the use of quotes list cases when the quotes should be used, like this:

> 1. Выделяются кавычками:
>
>    1. слова непривычные, малоупотребительные, на которые автор хочет обратить внимание…
>    2. слова, употребленные в необычном, особом значении…
>    3. слова, представляющие собой малоизвестные термины…
>    4. слова устарелые или, наоборот, совсем новые, если подчеркивается эта их особенность…
>    5. слова, сказанные иронически…
>    6. слова из чужого текста, цитаты…
>    7. слова, разъясняющие термины, выражения…
>    8. слова, употребленные в условном значении…

It is not a closed list, meaning that it does not forbid the use of quotes in other cases.

Here are some examples from the corpus where the quotes are used in the similar way:

> - Не в точности ее истории, другие, но это был все тот же извод на тему: «Однажды идет он, а навстречу…» или: «Жил у нас в Сатанове один мужчина…» А то и так: «Женился он на другой, и родила ему та двух сыновей. *[Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (2011-2015)]*
> - Потом один из них читает в найденном журнале статью «Поминки по столице» и рассуждает на тему «Горе тебе, Вавилон, город крепкий и расползающийся по швам», а хипстеры пишут на www. openspace. ru о том, что город сгубило отсутствие велосипедных дорожек и плохое качество латте. *[Ольга Брагина. Je t’aime. Moi non plus // Litera_Dnepr, 2012]*

In these cases, the quoted phrases are hardly direct speech.

---

> Could Leonid Volkov's punctuation be justified?

From my point of view, by putting it this way, Mr. Volkov is, literally, saying that the quoted phrase, in all its entirety, was the topic of Mr. Muratov's blog post.

This is a weirdly specific way to define the topic, and, unlike the Babylon example, it cannot be written off to a commonly known metaphor.

But if this is indeed what he intended to say, then yes, this punctuation is justified.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is simpler than what Quassnoi tries to convey.

In this particular sentence, the quotes are **grammatically required** and **do not imply direct speech** nor exact quotation. Instead, they "bracket" the part of the sentence that relates to the object "тема". Look, I just used the same construct again. Compare:

> Я задался вопросом "как быть" ещё до кризиса.

It is possible to avoid quotes, but not by simply removing them: this would be an error. You need to make it a proper subordinate clause:

> ...пост Муратова на тему о том, что Венедиктов...

So, grammatically, Volkov merely *names* the topic (тема), which, *in his view*, is the actual subject of the Muratov's post. Using quotes here, as opposed to "proper" indirect speech, first, is simpler, and second, conveys exactness of the statement. The statement (of this part of the sentence) is: "The topic of Muratov's post is exactly this: ..." This doesn't make it a quotation; it is still his (Volkov's) opinion. It might be wrong, but removing the quotes is not the way to fix it.